# Replace values in tibble in R 4.0

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I just upgraded to R 4.0.0 from R 3.6.2 and some functionality that I use to replace values in a tibble no longer works.  I can't find what I need to do now.  Does anyone know the "new" way?

```
library(tidyverse)
v <- c(1, 2, 3)
w <- c(4, 4)
i <- 1

# Does not work anymore
df <- tibble(a = v, b = v, c = v)
df[i, 2:3] <- w

# This used to work with tibbles
df.old <- data.frame(a = v, b = v, c = v)
df.old[i, 2:3] <- w
```

This is the error that I get with the tibble:

```
Error: Assigned data `w` must be compatible with row subscript `i`.
x 1 row must be assigned.
x Assigned data has 2 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure about `i <- i` ?

Comment: Oops sorry, should be i <- 1.  Edited

Comment: Yeah, I guess that works.  Pretty simple fix if not a little annoying to have to update all my old scripts.  It's also obvious enough that I should have figured it out before posting.  Thanks, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Actually, sorry that's not the right answer.  That replaces rows 2 and 3 in column 1.  I want to replace row 1 in column 2 and 3.  The answer from User112728748 below is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my R-devel version, the error message includes

```r
ℹ Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?
```

So the canonical way in this version is probably `df[i, 2:3] <- as.list(w)`, which works:

```r
library(tidyverse)
v <- c(1, 2, 3)
w <- c(4, 4)
i <- 1

df <- tibble(a = v, b = v, c = v)
df[i, 2:3] <- as.list(w)
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     4     4
#> 2     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works perfectly.  I've accepted this as the answer.  Thank you!